# Symfony 4 - Set DateTime

Tags: symfony, datetime, symfony4

so I've been following this Database and the Doctrine tutorial: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html

the only difference is that I added a `created_ts` field to it (among some other fields, but they work fine so no need to go into them).

I used the `make:entity` command to generate my class and the method for setting my `created_ts` got generated like this:

```
public function setCreatedTs(\DateTimeInterface $created_ts): self
{
    $this->created_ts = $created_ts;

    return $this;
}
```

So in my `/index` page I went to save a new entity using:

```
$category->setCreatedTs(\DateTimeInterface::class, $date);
```

I had a funny feeling this would error and I was right:

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\Category::setCreatedTs() must implement interface DateTimeInterface, string given
```

but I'm not sure how to implement the `DateTimeInterface` inside the function.. I tried googling but it shows a lot of `Symfony2` posts, a few I tried to no avail.

How do I set a `datetime` value in my entity from the `->set` method?

(if there is already an answer, please link. #symfonyScrub)

## update

```
# tried doing this:
$dateImmutable = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('now')); # also tried using \DateTimeImmutable

$category->setCategoryName('PHP');
$category->setCategoryBio('This is a category for PHP');
$category->setApproved(1);
$category->setGuruId(1);
$category->setCreatedTs($dateImmutable); # changes error from about a string to bool
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If your date is the current date, you can just do this:

```
$category->setCreatedTs(new \DateTime())
```

Your first error was caused by the `strtotime` function that returns a timestamp but the \DateTime constructor was expecting a `Y-m-d H:i:s` format.

That's why instead of creating a valid \DateTime, it returned false.

Even if it's unnecessary in this case, you should have done something like this to create a `\DateTime` based on a timestamp:

```
$date = new \DateTime('@'.strtotime('now'));
```