# Could not convert PHP value 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' of type 'string' to type 'datetime'. Expected one of the following types: null, DateTime In Symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony

This is my controller class

```
/**
 * @Route("/category/management/new", name="category_new", methods={"GET","POST"})
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function createCategory(Request $request): Response
{

    $date= new DateTime();
    $form =$this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('name',TextType::class)
        ->add('tags',TextType::class,[
            'required'=>false,
            ])
        ->add('parent', EntityType::class, [
            'label'=> 'If this is a subcategory please select a parent',
            'required'=>false,
            'class' => Category::class,
            'choice_label' => 'name',
        ])
        ->add('Create',SubmitType::class)
    ->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $user=$this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();

    var_dump($date);

    if($form->isSubmitted()){
        $data = $form->getData();
        $category = new Category();
        $category->setName($data['name']);
        $category->setTags($data['tags']);
        $category->setParent($data['parent']);
        $category->setCreatedAt(new DateTime());
        $category->setCreatedBy($user);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($category);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('category_management'));
    }

    return $this->render('category_management/create.html.twig',[
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
```

i've tried running it without setCreatedAt(new Datetime()) and relying on the DB to do the work but it still errors out.

Tried making changes in the entity class and directly setting New Datetime in the setCreatedAt method

All these didnt work and im stuck

Comment: $createdAt = 'CURRENT_TIMESTAM', like this you pass a string to datetime attribute.

what about pass it in the constructor

`function __construct() {
$this->createdAt = new Datetime();
}
`

Comment: i tried passing it in the constructor but it still errored out

Comment: before your last edit, I saw $createdtAt  = 'CURRENT_TIMESTAM', so remove = 'CURRENT_TIMESTAM',

Comment: Still the same error. The ironic thing is that my CRUD for my user class uses the same methods and annotations and works fine

Comment: you said "still the same error" , but if you delete "CURRENT_TIMESTAM" , the error should be changed and no more display "CURRENT_TIMESTAM" in the error message. Try to clear the cache if you use prod env

Comment: See this answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/50467860/12232340

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59427778/symfony-4-must-implement-interface-datetimeinterface-error this solved my problem

Comment: Maybe this lib is helpfull for you : https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/tree/v2.4.x/lib/Gedmo 
Replace createdAt in your entity with:  use TimestampableEntity;